# How to allow dot or comma in UITextField in calculation?

Tags: swift

I am newbie in coding. I just started to learn #swift and trying yo make a calculation app. My problem is my UITextField doesn't work with dot or comma.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var ilkLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ikinciLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sonucLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ilk2Label: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ikinci2Label: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sonuc2Label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ilk3Label: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ikinci3Label: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sonuc3Label: UILabel!

    var sonuc:Double = 0
    var sonuc2:Double = 0
    var sonuc3:Double = 0
    var deneme:Double = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }



    @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        func forTrailingZero(temp: Double) -> String {
            let tempVar = String(format: "%g", temp)
            return tempVar
        }

        deneme = Double(Int(ikinciLabel.text!)! + 100 / 100 * Int(ilkLabel.text!)!)
        sonucLabel.text = String(forTrailingZero(temp:  Double(ikinciLabel.text!)! / 14.56     ) )


    }


    @IBAction func plus2Btn(_ sender: Any) {



    }

    @IBAction func plus3Btn(_ sender: Any) {


    }

}
```

I expect to make calculation like 1.4 + 2.35 but when i try the app crashes. I can only calculate whole number like 2 + 2.

Comment: Yup, well, `Int(ikinciLabel.text!)!` means “crash if the text is not an Int” so you got what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you! Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@matt is right. If the text in ikinciLabel is not an Int, the app crashes. You tell it to crash by using the force unwrap operator: !.

**In general**

You should only force-unwrap things when you are absolutely sure that the thing you want to unwrap is not nill. In all other cases you should if-let or guard-let the optional, use the nil-coalescing operator (??) (or other ways to unwrap optionals) and handle the nil-case.

**In your case**

if you want to allow the user to enter floating point numbers using either a comma or a dot, you could simply replace every comma with a dot like so:

```
let enteredTextWithoutComma = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
```

This new constant is an optional. To safely make a Double out of it, do:

```
guard let enteredTextWithoutCommaUnwraped = enteredTextWithoutComma,
      let enteredNumber = Double(enteredTextWithoutCommaUnwraped) else {
   // one of the two actions didn't work. Maybe the entered phrase was not a number
   // do something
   return
}
// here you can use the variable enteredNumber. It is now a Double (not an Optional)
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!